# How do you consistently set default values for a TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I display an alert using the following code, the default value is shown the first time. However, when I close it and open it again, the default value is not displayed. Does the alert text box not consider retaining the default value?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
struct AlertTestView: View {
    @State var editAlert: Bool = false
    @State var editing_name: String = "hogehoge"
    var body: some View {
        Text("editing_name:\(editing_name)")
        Button("Alert"){
            editAlert = true
        }
        Button("Alert with other default value"){
            editing_name = "piyo piyo"
            editAlert = true
        }
        .alert("enter_new_book_name", isPresented: $editAlert) {
            TextField("", text: $editing_name)
            Button("change",action: {
            })
            Button("cancel", role: .cancel, action: {
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use onChange for editAlert and reset your property whenever editAlert changes to false.

Comment: `...the default value is not displayed.`, what is displayed?
 Note, there is another `.alert` signature,
 `.alert("enter_new_book_name", isPresented: $editAlert, presenting: editing_name) {....`
and also using `actions: ...` with a `TextField(...)` that could be used.

Comment: Looking at this again I wonder if the purpose of the "change" button in the alert is to persist or send the content somewhere then I believe that button action is probably also the best place to reset the property.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextField` in the alert uses a `Binding` to your state variable `editing_name`. So every time the alert is shown, the text field begins with the "default" value of this state variable.

I don't see it behaving in any strange way at all. If you use the first button to launch the alert, then it displays the current value of `editing_name`. This starts as "hogehoge", but it will change if the user enters anything into the field, or if the second button is used to launch the alert. Then it never goes back to the default "hogehoge".

If you want it to begin with the default of "hogehoge" every time the first button is used then you need to set this value in the button action callback, just like you are doing with the second button:

```swift
Button("Alert") {
    editing_name = "hogehoge"
    editAlert = true
}
```